# Let $Z$ and $A$ symmetric matrices of $m\times m$ such that $Z\succeq 0$. Shows a characterization of $\mbox{Tr}(ZA)$.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, trace, symmetric-matrices

Let  $Z$ and $A$ be $m \times m$ symmetric matrices such that $Z \succeq 0$, where $\succeq$ means "positive semi-definite". Show that there is a $\mu\geq 0$ such that

$$\begin{equation}\mbox{Tr}(ZA)=\mu\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^{m}}\left\{y^{T}Ay\right\}\end{equation}\mbox{ }\mbox{ }\mbox{ }(*)$$ where $\mbox{Tr}$ means "trace".

Also show the converse, that is, given $\mu\geq 0$ and $A$ symmetric matrix of dimension $m \times m$, then there is $Z$ be a symmetric matrices of $m\times m$ such that $Z\succeq 0$ and we have $(*)$.

**Remark:** I've tried everything but my attempts do not lead to a good destination, I appreciate any suggestion or solution, or if applicable, any reference to a book that addresses this problem.

Comment: What is the sum over inside the sup?

Comment: @Tom It was a typo, this corrected already.

Comment: there is no finite sup with $y$ not restricted. Probably the rayleigh qoutient is meant, sup, actually max, when $|y|=1,$ meaning the sum of $y_j^2$ is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obviously false: take $m=2$, 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix},\qquad Z=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then Tr $ZA=-1$, and $\sup(\dots)=0$.